# Reading notification properties per app (ON/OFF) on Android and iOS

Tags: android, ios, notifications, push-notification

Is there a way of reading the property refering to Notification of an App, in iOS and Android?

I intend to offer a screen where the client may see if Notifications are enabled ou disabled in an operating system level. If it's off, there may be a tutorial for the client (my app do not intend to turn it ON, just read) in order to enable it.

Thanks.

Comment: you cant "turn off" notifications on and really

Comment: I just want to read this property. I do not intend to turn it ON or OFF.

Comment: there is no property to read

Comment: Thanks @tyczj. You're talking about Android, right? How about iOS?